# Split the given string into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Suppose the given string is:

> [[1]] is for cars, as [[2]] is for bikes

I want to split the string into an array of string using regex or any other way, when *[[any number]]* (for example: [[1]], [[2]]) is encountered.

```
[ 
   [[1]], 
   " is for cars, as ", 
   [[2]],
   " is for bikes"
]

What I have tried: 

"[[1]] is for cars, as [[2]] is for bikes".split(/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/gi);

This returns ",1, is for cars, as ,2, is for bikes"
```

Comment: Try this: `"[[1]] is for cars, as [[2]] is for bikes".split(/\s*(\[\[\d+\]\])\s*/gi).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: It works, but can you explain what filter here does ? @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1. `.split` is using capture group at wrong place i.e. you're capturing only digits instead of `[[<digits>]]`
2. Since splitting pattern is found at the start as well so you will need to use  `.filter` method to get rid of an empty string from the resulting array.

```js
const str = "[[1]] is for cars, as [[2]] is for bikes";
var arr = str.split(/(\[\[\d+\]\])/gi).filter(Boolean);
console.log(arr);
/*
[
  "[[1]]",
  " is for cars, as ",
  "[[2]]",
  " is for bikes"
]
*/
```

Comment: How can whitespace be included in the string, as it ignores whitespace after words? (ex is for cars, as ) it outputs (is for cars, as)

Comment: Just remove `\s*` from both sides to make it `str.split(/(\[\[\d+\]\])/gi).filter(Boolean)` but your expected output is not showing leading/trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Use **positive lookbehind** and **positive lookahead**

```js
const myString = "[[1]] is for cars, as [[2]] is for bikes";
const output = myString.split(/(?<=\[\[\d+\]\])\s|\s(?=\[\[\d+\]\])/g);
console.log(output);
```